# Undefined index: sui_image_caption in

Tags: images, shortcode

I am getting this error:

Notice: Undefined index: sui_image_caption in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/source/submit_user_images.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined index: sui_image_category in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/source/submit_user_images.php on line 73

I have installed this plugin; https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/allow-users-to-submit-images-to-your-wordpress-site--wp-22601

It says error on line 73 which is:

echo sui_get_upload_image_form($sui_image_caption = $_POST['sui_image_caption'], $sui_image_category = $_POST['sui_image_category']);

Can anyone help me fix this issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Questions about plugins are not usually answered here (or encouraged). You should contact the plugin's support page.

But, the error is in the plugin called 'source' - as described by the error message. Whatever that plugin is, go to their support page.

If you want to disable that plugin temporarily, rename it's folder (wp-content/plugins/source ) with an FTP program of your hosting place's File Manager. Then reload the admin page, go to the plugin page, and you'll see that the plugin is now disabled. Contact them for further support.